# Optimize bucket sort

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, sorting, optimization

How I'am supposed to create a optimized bucket sort. I'm having the given intervals and probability which tells What is the chance to have a number from given interval.
On Wikipedia is told that I have to create it based on density but how?

How do i know how many bucket i'm creating for given interval of numbers?

I tried to create bigger number of buckets when the interval has bigger probability but i finished with more question than answers

Example:
Table with intervals and probability
[ (0,5,0.45), (3,15,0.22), (15,30,0.33) ]
i.e numbers from 0 to 5 has a 0.45 chance to be in a array that I have to sort.
3 to 15 0.22 etc.

Array = [1.43, 4.55, 2.17, 17.33, 7.11, 2.14]

Result = [1.43, 2.14, 2.17, 4.55, 7.11, 17.33]

The key is to take advantage of given probability and intervals to have O(n) with bucket sort.

That's my code of how I'm doing the buckets but it's inefficient as hell

```
k = len(P)
boundries = []

for el in P:
    # el = (a,b,c)
    a = el[0]
    b = el[1]
    c = el[2]
    boundries.append(a)
    start = a
    for i in range(a,b + 1):
        end = (b - a) / (k * c) + start
        B.append([])
        boundries.append(end)
        start = end
```

Comment: `[ (0,5,0.45), (3,15,0.22), (15,30,0.33) ]` this interval has overlaps in the first two tuples.  did you mean for it to have overlaps ?   ie.  what happens to the number 4 which would fall into both and therefore have two probabilities ?

Comment: P is not defined here, but I'm assuming it's your 3 probability ranges. But to get O(n) with bucket sort, you want k (the number of buckets) to be set to n (the size of the input)

Comment: Yes, the intervals can overlap. I know that we need to use density and make it so that if we have `k` buckets, we want to have a 1/k chance for each number to go into a bucket.
P is an array with the intervals and probability. Looks like that
`P = [(1,5,0.25), (4,16,0.75)]`
`P = [(a_1,b_1,c_1), (a_2,b_2,c_2), ..., (a_k,b_k,c_k)]}`

For example:
`T = [6.1, 1.2, 1.5, 3.5, 4.5, 2.5, 3.9, 7.8]`
`P = [(1, 5, 0.75) , (4, 8, 0.25)]`

Comment: And I don't know how to modify the ordinary bucket sort to get it still O(n).

Comment: This is a duplicate of your previous question: [How to create buckets in bucket sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71622332/how-to-create-buckets-in-bucket-sort). Please do not duplicate questions. Instead, improve the question so that it is answerable and can be reopened.